# Setting up domainame to a shared hosting site

Tags: dns, hosting

Not sure if this is the right stack but I need help setting up dns for a domainname that I need to point to a shared hosting site here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last image is the ip adress and dns ip for the shared hosting site. The rest are images from the cpanel of the registrar for the domain name I want to use. Should I change the Name Server 1 and 2 to the name servers provided by the shared hosting site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll need to change the name server's to the ones required by your hosting site.
There may be other DNS settings required also, which your domain name hosting provider may or may not allow you to do.

If you don't get the flexibility you require with the DNS services provided by your domain name host, I'd recommend checking out freedns.afraid.org.